# Canvas redrawing/erasing when window resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, canvas

Im having a few issues resetting my canvas when the window re-sizes or after a given amount of time. I want to complete reset and have it fresh. The problem is if your wait a few minutes (Because the refresh runs) or you re-size your window, everything starts to go haywire. I believe its because its drawing the canvas over top of an existing one and that's whats bleeding through. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```js
// Constellations
function constellations() {
 var pr = (function () {
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
  dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
  bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
  ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
  ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
  ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
  ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

  return dpr / bsr;
 })();

 function t() {
  this.x = Math.random() * o.width, this.y = Math.random() * o.height, this.vx = -.5 + Math.random(), this.vy = -.5 + Math.random(), this.radius = Math.random()
 }

 function d() {
  for (a.clearRect(0, 0, o.width, o.height), i = 0; i < r.nb; i++) r.array.push(new t), dot = r.array[i], dot.create();
  dot.line(), dot.animate()
 }

 var o = document.querySelector("#constellations");
 var ratio = pr;
 o.width = $(window).width() * ratio;
 o.height = $(window).height() * ratio;
 o.style.width = $(window).width() + "px";
 o.style.height = $(window).height() + "px";
 o.style.display = "block";

 var n = "#1A2732";
 var linecolor = "#FF535A";

 a = o.getContext("2d");
 a.setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
 a.clearRect(0, 0, o.width, o.height);
 a.fillStyle = n;
 a.lineWidth = .1;
 a.strokeStyle = linecolor;

 var e = {
  x: 30 * o.width / 100,
  y: 30 * o.height / 100
 },
 r = {
  nb: o.width / 10,
  distance: 80,
  d_radius: 150,
  array: []
 };
 t.prototype = {
  create: function() {
   a.beginPath(), a.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !1), a.fill()
  },
  animate: function() {
   for (i = 0; i < r.nb; i++) {
    var t = r.array[i];
    t.y < 0 || t.y > o.height ? (t.vx = t.vx, t.vy = -t.vy) : (t.x < 0 || t.x > o.width) && (t.vx = -t.vx, t.vy = t.vy), t.x += t.vx, t.y += t.vy
   }
  },
  line: function() {
   for (i = 0; i < r.nb; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < r.nb; j++) i_dot = r.array[i], j_dot = r.array[j], i_dot.x - j_dot.x < r.distance && i_dot.y - j_dot.y < r.distance && i_dot.x - j_dot.x > -r.distance && i_dot.y - j_dot.y > -r.distance && i_dot.x - e.x < r.d_radius && i_dot.y - e.y < r.d_radius && i_dot.x - e.x > -r.d_radius && i_dot.y - e.y > -r.d_radius && (a.beginPath(), a.moveTo(i_dot.x, i_dot.y), a.lineTo(j_dot.x, j_dot.y), a.stroke(), a.closePath())
  }
 };

 var refresh = setInterval(d, 1e3 / 30);

 $(window).resize(function() {
  window.clearInterval(refresh);
  constellations();
 });
}constellations();
```

```css
<canvas id="constellations"></canvas>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To see it working in action. Just re-size the divider and watch. It may even be a case of reseting the function. Im not sure what should be done to resolve this issue. Its a weird one.
https://jsfiddle.net/v4dqgazr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, as the browser is being resized, `$(window).resize()` is triggered continuously as the resizing is in progress. You can use [David Walsh's debounce method](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to solve this issue.

Here is an update ***[demo with event logs](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/v4dqgazr/5/)***

The debounce method looks like this

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Comment: So is that what is actually happening? Its just firing a hundred times in the window? That the visual flashing part after re-sizing?

Comment: yes, resize is continuously being called as the resizing is in progress. I updated the demo link with event logging. Check that now.

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you. I see why it has been happening now.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to give some insight on what's happening:

Every instant that the window is being resized, `constellations()` is being called. Apparently different browsers handle this differently, Dhiraj's answer should help you.

I added code like this, which shows you that many instances are being created and are running:

```
function constellations(instanceID) {

...

function d() {
    console.log("Draw called from instance id: " + instanceID;
    ...
}


$(window).resize(function() {
    window.clearInterval(refresh);
    constellations(Math.random());
});
```

You'll see a lot of log calls being made once you resize.